# Use guard with double-optional

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, option-type, guard

When I want to use a guard to make sure a double-optional value is not nil, what are my options?

```swift
let something: Bool?? = true

guard let anything: Bool = something else {
  return
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **Guard** as well as **if let**

```
if let getValue = something, let value = getValue {
    print(value) 
}

guard let getValue = something , let value = getValue else {
  return
}
```

You can also use **FlatMap**

```
if let value = something.flatMap({ $0 }) {
    print(value)  
}
```

If you have any level of optionals e.g 3,4,5,7 you will get the value with **Conditionally cast**

```
  let something: Bool????? = true
    if let value = something as? Bool {
        print(value) // prints true
    }
```

Comment: I like the cast!

Comment: flatMap is best as it doesn't need to be edited if the type changes

Comment: yeah you are right boss